# How to remove the borders around images inserted over a cell?

Tags: image, google-sheets

Is it possible to remove the borders around images that have been Inserted Over a Cell?

In the example pic; The left-side is how it appears while editing the sheet, with no borders as desired. The right-side is how it appears in the published sheet, with an unwanted border.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yy7b.jpg)

I have turned Gridlines Off in the View menu.
I have tried using the Border options, which don't affect the image. The border options only affect whatever cell is also selected (and one cell 'has' to be selected - I can't just select the image on its own. See next example pic)

[example image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw7oI.jpg)

Notice it appears that the image which i want to remove the border from is selected, but then also notice the cell to the right is also selected. The border option only affects the cell, not the image.

Changing the BG colour so that the borders cannot be seen isn't an option because i have various images and background colours.
Also, inserting the image as a Drawing isn't an option because any gif images are then static/unanimated.

Thank you.

edit: I did spend a lot of time searching for an answer for this and noticed someone asked a similar question almost 2 years ago, which received no answers.
Seems i will have to find a totally different app to use just because of that one issue. I'm not sure why google would force borders around images and have no option to remove them. I wish i had known that before completing everything and publishing it.